# How to parse this json in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

```
{
  "segmentId": "b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4",
  "diffFields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "name",
      "valueBefore": null,
      "valueAfter": "new-segment-name"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "active",
      "valueBefore": null,
      "valueAfter": true
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above json I have an array of `diffFields` . I am trying to parse this in snowflake get the array of columns instead of rows.
I tried flatten, but this flatten it as rows.

I am trying to parse this in dbt to create another table from the above json with table structure as

```
create table some_table (
field_one,
--if `name` is present in the above json I want that to be 2nd column
-- if `active` is present in the above json i want that to be 3nd column 
)
)
```

Comment: Arrays are naturally rows, rather than columns, but I see that in your case it is being used to store name-value pairs, instead.  Once you flatten, have you looked at the PIVOT functions to accomplish what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I would flatten it like

```
WITH data as (
    select parse_json('
{
  "segmentId": "b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4",
  "diffFields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "name",
      "valueBefore": null,
      "valueAfter": "new-segment-name"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "active",
      "valueBefore": null,
      "valueAfter": true
    }
  ]
}') as json
)
select 
    json:segmentId::text as seg_id,
    f.value:fieldName::text as fieldName,
    f.value:valueBefore as valueBefore,
    f.value:valueAfter as valueAfter 
from data, table(flatten(input=>json:diffFields)) f
```

which gives:

| SEG_ID | FIELDNAME | VALUEBEFORE | VALUEAFTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4 | name | null | "new-segment-name" |
| b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4 | active | null | true |

but those variant data nulls are not real nulls. so you want to use something like [is_null_value](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is_null_value.html) to test and covert to real nulls

### To select array parts:

```
select json:segmentId::text
    ,max(iff(f.value:fieldName::text = 'name', f.value, null)) as name_object
    ,max(iff(f.value:fieldName::text = 'active', f.value, null)) as active_object
from data, table(flatten(input=>json:diffFields)) f
group by 1;
```

gives:

| JSON:SEGMENTID::TEXT | NAME_OBJECT | ACTIVE_OBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4 | { "fieldName": "name", "valueAfter": "new-segment-name", "valueBefore": null } | { "fieldName": "active", "valueAfter": true, "valueBefore": null } |

Comment: I was able to get this. 
I have another table of the format
```create table create_table_data (
id,
name,
active
)
```
In dbt , i join these these to get the latest. The json above is sent when update occurs on the `fieldName`. 
I want a new table with the latest data from `create_table` and json above

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuickTable to connect snowflake and do JSON parse use QuickTable. QuickTable can generate related SQL that is compatible with Snowflake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).